# css import from another server

Tags: css, import

it is possible to import the css file from another server? let's say i have my html on www.mysite.com can i import my css like this?

```
<link href="www.anothersite.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, any full url is valid for css.  You'll want to include http:// though.

```
<link href="http://www.anothersite.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably want to start the url with `http://`, otherwise some browsers will interpret that as `http://your.currenturl.com/www.anothersite.com/style.css`.

Answer (score 4):

Just to extend the other guys comments, and particularly for those using SSL certificates, you might want to write the href as "//www.anothersite.com/style.css" to avoid issues with an SSL site requesting content from a non SSL site.

Note that you exclude the "http:" or "https:" bit from the URL.

The browser will automatically add either "http:" or "https:".