# Receiving a 403 Forbidden on static files but I can't use SSH

Tags: nginx, hosting, web-hosting, http-status-code-403, plesk

I've been looking around for hours on how to fix this. Every answer I look at involves using a cli to assign permissions and change user groups and the like. Unfortunately, my host will not allow me to use SSH so all I can do is use the Plesk 12.5.30 cpanel. This means my options are very limited in terms of problem solving.

So far I have tried assigning 755 permissions to everything via my FTP client, creating a new FTP user, and moving the forbidden file to the root

Relavent info:

- the only forbidden file is my main css file
- the files are sitting in a subdomain
- creating a blank HTML template file via the cpanel in the same folder as the css file does not throw a 403
- putting the css in a style tag in the HTML template causes a 403
- I hate my host but I can't switch

Is there anything I can do short of pleading with my boss' boss to change hosting providers?

Comment: if you really hate your host you could, to the very least, [place that particulat css file elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645860/css-import-from-another-server)

Comment: Have you tried changing the permissions on the Plesk File Manager of your domain, changing permissions through the FTP is useless in some cases, by default Plesk provides an FTP user which is a completely different user from the user running your application.

Comment: @OctavioDurana I just looked and the css file is 644, the css folder and subdomain folder are both 755. Also, the subdomain folder is in the psaserv group while the css folder and file are in the psacln group

Comment: The 403 response is not necessarily permissions related. What access and error log entries are there?

Comment: @RichardSmith the only error logs I get are about not having a robots.txt file. I created one and now it's not logging any errors despite the 403 persisting

Comment: those sound like client logs, do you have any access to server logs?